# MalformedURLException in OSMDROID

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

i trying to download a maptile from url and show it on my map

```
String prova = "http://a.tile.stamen.com/toner/0/0/0.png";
        try {
            prova = URLEncoder.encode(urll,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("URL","Errore URL\n\n");
        }

        final ITileSource customTileSource = new CustomTileSource("SomeName",3,14,256,
                ".png",new String[]{prova});
        final TilesOverlay overlay = new TilesOverlay(new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext(),customTileSource),getBaseContext());
        overlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(0);
        map.getOverlays().add(overlay);
```

but I find an error of this kind

```
OsmDroid: IOException downloading MapTile: /3/1/7 : java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: http%3A%2F%2F%7Bs%7D.tile.openstreetmap.org%2F%7Bz%7D%2F%7Bx%7D%2F%7By%7D.png
```

How to solve this problem ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are using URLEncoder to encode your URL. URLencoder is not ment to be used for encoding of whole URLs.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

> Utility class for HTML form encoding. This class contains static
>   methods for converting a String to the
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format. For more information
>   about HTML form encoding, consult the HTML specification.

You don't need to use any encoding for your tilesource URL.

Also it is probably incorrect to includ "0/0/0.png" in your tilousource URL, this pert should be filled in by OSMDroid. But I cannot be sure how the CustomTileSource is implemented so it may be different in your case.

For more information about including of custom tilesources check the [documentation for osmdroid](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/Map-Sources.html).

Comment: @PasqualeCelardo I dont' think so. The error you observed says, that the url is not valid and shows invalid (encoded)  url.